# codeigniter email verification

Tags: php, codeigniter, email-validation

Hi everyone i am trying to send an email verification sms to a registered user. the message is getting sent and the confirmation work but the 'status' row in the data base doesn't update to 1 after authentication clicked.

here is my code CONTROLLER

```
    public function verify($email_code, $email_address) {
    if($this->user_model->verifyEmail($email_code, $email_address)){
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/email_validated');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
    } else {
        echo 'error'.$this->config->item('admin_email');    
    }

}
```

here is my code MODEL

```
public function send_validation_email() {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $sql = "SELECT id, register_date FROM users WHERE email = '" .$email ."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->row();

    $this->email_code = md5((string)$row->register_date);
    $email_code = $this->email_code;

    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $this->email->from($this->config->item('bot_email'),'talkativs');
    $this->email->to('xxxxx@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('activatorrrrr');

    $message .= '<p> Dear ' . $username.',</p>';

    $message .= '<p> confim mail sharpaly <a href="' . base_url().'users/verify/'.$email.'/'.$email_code.'">click here</a></p>';
    $message .= '<p> Thanks</p>';

    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();

    if ($this->email->send()){
        return "sent";
    } else {
        return "failed to send";    
    }

}


 function verifyEmail($email_code, $email_address) {
    $data = array('status' => 1);
    $this->db->where('email', $email_address);
    $this->db->where('md5(register_date)', $email_code);
    return $this->db->update('users', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Your method has wrong mapping for parameters..***

```
public function verify($email_code, $email_address) {
        if($this->user_model->verifyEmail($email_code, $email_address)){
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/email_validated');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
        } else {
            echo 'error'.$this->config->item('admin_email');    
        }
    }
```

***It must be like :***

```
public function verify($email_address, $email_code) {
    if($this->user_model->verifyEmail($email_code, $email_address)){
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/email_validated');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
    } else {
        echo 'error'.$this->config->item('admin_email');    
    }
}
```

*You sending the email like below example:*

```
'<p> confirm mail sharply <a href="' . base_url().'users/verify/'.$email.'/'.$email_code.'">click here</a></p>';
```

*Which produce the following output in email:*

```
<p>confirm mail sharply <a href="http:// www.site.com/users/verify/example@email.com/AC67">click here</a></p>
```

***Notice the format of link:***

> users{**Controller**}/verify{**Method**}/example@email.com{**First**
>   **Param**}/AC67{**Second Param**}

*So your method must be use* ***method ($email, $code)***... simple.. :)

***Because CodeIgniter takes url parameters in same order as they supplied..***

Comment: Thanks i literarily had migraine trying to figure this out. I really appreciate it. am having trouble sending a password reset link and updating the password field

Comment: Glad :) it could help you.. Now your email working..?

Comment: sure. it is working fine but  am having trouble sending a password reset link and updating the password field

Comment: You can send a unique id or hash value within your email, and you can save that in users table. when user click on that link, check hash value in their table. If found start a session by user id and show them password update form. After submitted their password update the users password and destroy the session and redirect the users to login page with message..hey your password updated and now you login with ur new password... Dont forget to make hash field column empty after password update successfully. ..

Comment: hi please i have a question and would be really grateful if you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006565/passing-users-details-in-codeigniter-using-session/45006902?noredirect=1#comment76987509_45006902

Comment: @olar19 done Bro!! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001657/codeigniter-users-data/45019355#45019355

Comment: I really appreciate you. I left you a comment kindly help modify my own codes . Cheers.

Comment: hi Bro. i am unable to ask question now in the forum but would like to ask how i can upload multiple images to the database and display all as carousel per user in the view

Comment: Hi @olar19, You can follow this link and can create your own.. https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-multiple-files-images/

Comment: Thanks. Bro i am really grateful . you've assisted me a lot in this project.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Like and Dislike button in codeigniter when clicked it adds one to the like and dislike value.
The button will be saved in database as int on the mySql questions table (the questions table contains id,body,date,like,fields) and every time the button has gets clicked it the like or dislike field is updated in the database by adding 1 to it.
I have tried thinking about this but am getting confused.
If anybody has a simple code with the Model, View, and Controller, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Hi please i have been trying to chat with you but i am unable to. any way of reaching you?