# Codeigniter User's Data

Tags: codeigniter, view

Hi guys I have a **User** controller and **User_model** model. I want to be able to retrieve and display a logged in users email and phone number from the database to a **view** after the user is logged in. any idea how I could go about this would be appreciated and if codes could be written to demonstrate I would be very happy.

MODEL

```
   public function login($username, $password){
        //validation
        $this->db->select('id, email, username');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        return $result->row(0)->id;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
    }

        public function get_user($username){

            $this->db->where('username', $username);  
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            return $query->result();
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function login(){
    $data['title'] = 'Login';

    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {

        // fetching user
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
        //Encrypted password
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

    //login user
    $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);

    if($user_id){
        //creating session
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => TRUE,
        );

   $this->session->set_userdata('user_data',$user_data);            
                // Set message to be sent
    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_login', 'Welcome');
    redirect('posts');
    } else {



        // Set message to be sent
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_fail', 'Login Failed');
    redirect('users/login'); 
    }

    }

}

public function get_user()
  {

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data['results'] = $this->user_model->get_user($username);
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

  }
```

Comment: Re edit your question with your controller code, and model How to place code in question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I am asking because i don't have it in my model , controller and view . any idea how to get users details from database after session has been passed from login

Comment: From the doc (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data) I understand that you have to pass only your array to user_data. Like this $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

Comment: I have already answer your previous question, you don't need to ask it again.

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's _very very_ insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: i know and would hash the password just answer to my question is what i need

Comment: I don't get what your issue actually is. Just fetch all the columns you want in the login query and store them in the session. Simply return the user object instead of just the ID and store what you want to store in the session. Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes from my question

Comment: Asking the same question is not gone help you. So stop doing it. Otherwise SO will take actions against you.

Comment: If you really had too - why cant you just create a new model function like get user_details - passing in the users ID and using that... That way you dont have to modify your login model method... even though it's another database call it's not that pricey in terms of performance... Now you should be able to do that... yes?

Comment: i tried that initially but didn't get it through

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: CONTROLLER:   public function get_user()
      {
        
            $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $data['username'] = $this->user_model->get_users($username);
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('posts/index');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

      }

Comment: MODEL:     public function get_users($username){
        
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where('username', $username);  
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            return $query->row_array();
}

Comment: Read the codeigniter manual and there are plenty of tutorials on you tube.

Answer (score 1):

***There is basic problem in your Controller***

> ***Session Data Problem:*** *In your Controller you storing all array data in CodeIgniter Session:*

*the 'user_data' would work like array key, and all other array will be assign as keys data;*

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $user_data);
```

and you retrieving/checking the session data by using ***`$this->session->userdata('logged_in')`*** and ***`$this->session->userdata('username')`***, It's wrong my friend. You can get user data session by ***`$this->session->userdata('user_data')['username']`*** or ***`$this->session->userdata['user_data']['username']`*** ...

> ***Because the session would be like;***

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1499791562

    // This is the array key 'user_data' where your array data stores

    [user_data] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [username] => scott
            [email] => scott.dimon@example.com
            [phone_number] => 1234567890
            [first_name] => Scott
            [logged_in] => 1
        )

)
```

### ***So, you have to have use 'user_data' with session to get your data***

One thing I would like to share with everyone, ***Always Read The Docs and manual Carefully. Believe me if you read before the start, your code would be more nicer and cleaner... Ha ha ha ha ha.. ;) :|***

Comment: I am really glad you took time to do this for me. but i want the user's email and username alone to be available on the navbar.  so it is not only in the post view that the users details would show

Comment: @olar19, Just check updated answer, Its quick and to the point... for you

Answer (score 0):

> When you login if you set the **users_id** in session you can get the information like

Read manual also

1. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows
2. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Make sure you autoload session, and database.

**Examples ONLY below.**

Filename: User_model.php

```
 class User_model extends CI_Model {

 public function get_user($id)
 {
     $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
     $user_query = $this->db->get('yourtable');

     return $user_query->row_array();
 }

 }
```

Filename: Dashboard.php

Controller

```
 <?php


 class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct()
      {
         parent::__construct();

         if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id'))
         {
            redirect('logoutcontroller');
         }

         $this->load->model('user_model');
      }

      public function index()
      {
          $userdata = $this->user_model->get_user($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

          /** You can use what you want example 
                 $data['email'] = $userdata['email'];
          **/
          $data['username'] = $userdata['username'];

          $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
      }

 }
```

View

```
<?php echo $username;?>
```

Comment: undefined variable username

Comment: What do you have set in session the code above was only example You can have you dont have to have username Its a bit hard to guess with out seen what you tried so far.

Comment: i would post my user model and controller now

Comment: @olar19 On your model get_user you have `return $query->result();` change to `return $query->row_array();`

Comment: @olar19 Don't use md5 for passwords md5 can be very easy hacked these days use php built in password generate http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php  and verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: When get user info I would get by user id, not username

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to carry the logged in user detail.

This is your model code:

```
//In your model
$query = $this->db
        ->select('id,email,phone')
        ->where(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])     
        ->where('status','1')
        ->get('users');
    $user_data = $query->row_array();

    if (!empty($user_data)) {                    
        return $user_data;
    } else {                
        return FALSE;
    }
```

In side the controller where you get the user data if `username` & `password` is correct. Here you can put the user data on session:

```
    //In Side Controller

    $user_data = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);

     if(isset($user_data) && !empty($user_data)){        

     // you can directly add the `$user_data` to the session as given billow.       
    // set user data in session
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $user_data);
```

Now after putting a data on session you can retrive it any where, on any view or in side morel, controller.

```
    //retrive the user data in any view
    //To echo in view Inside your view code.
    <?php
       $session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
       $user_email = $session_data['email'];
       $user_phone = $session_data['phone'];
       $user_id = $session_data['id'];
    ?>

   <?= $user_phone ?> OR <?php echo $user_phone; ?>
   <?= $user_email ?> OR <?php echo $user_email; ?>
```

On Your `$this->load->view('users/login', $data);` this view. Where the `HTML` & `PHP` code placed.
Example:

```
<html>
// Your View Page
</body>

        <?php
           $session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
           $user_email = $session_data['email'];
           $user_phone = $session_data['phone'];
           $user_id = $session_data['id'];
        ?>

<h1> Logged In User Email: <?= $user_email ?> </h1>
<h1> Logged In User Phone: <?= $user_phone ?> </h1>

<body>

</html>
```

Note: Once You save the user data inside the session then you don't need to pass that data to the view form controller. You just need to echo it where you need that.

Comment: It doesn't display on the screen.

Comment: Can you please add what you have done using this on your question.

Comment: I added your suggestions to the login function in the model and controller and added the view just like you suggested but it doesn't display anything

Comment: I think  my updated answer is enough to get the session data and view  it on the view.

Comment: $result->num_rows() == 1 from this line in the model is different from yours  . you used $get_candidate_data->num_rows() == 1  can you use my own code and make the necessary adjustments for me. Thanks

Comment: you could kindly modify my own model and controller . i am getting more confused please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to load session library first. like

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then after you can save your data into session like,

```
$newdata = array(
    'username'  => 'johndoe',
    'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Then where ever you require at controller you can retrive session data like,

```
$data['session_data'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

and then pass to your view,

```
$this->load->view('data', $data);
```

and then access that data into your view with the key,

```
<?= $session_data['username']; ?>
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: should this be added in the login function or i should create another function. or you can kindly copy my own codes and help modify it . Thanks in advance

Comment: But u need to retrive your session data where ever you require,
and then after -you need to pass it to view by the help of any variable,
as i said in my above code.

Comment: Kindly copy my codes and help adjust it as your response is confusing . please. you can use it as a new answer . i have already loaded session library globally.

Comment: i added it and it doesn't display in the view     $user_data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'username' => $username,
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
            );
              $data['session_data'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
            $this->load->view('data', $data);

Comment: Ok, you kind of need to understand what is going on... Copying and pasting in code and saying it doesn't work suggests you are not looking at the concepts here. Do you know how views work? Do you know how sessions work... Have you read the user_guide at all?

Comment: yes. i passed the data to the view but it doesn't display the email or username or any detail

Comment: $this->load->view('User_Login', $data);
here the user login is your view name.

just like you are redirecting to posts.
and $data is Session data variable

Comment: still doesn't show. from my question i am able to login the user with session . i now want to be able to access all of the users details from the database but it's not showing. if you could help modify my own code to show my error or what i am supposed to include

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
public function login($username, $password){
$db = $this->db;

    //validation
    $db->select('id, email, username');
    $db->where('username', $username);
    $db->where('password', $password);
    $db->where('status', 1);
    $result = $db->get('users')->row_array();

return empty($result['id']) ? false : $result['id'];
}
```

With a unique index on username you won't need to check the number of rows as it will be limited to 1.

Comment: it doesn't can you please help modify my own model and controller ?

Comment: Have you implemented my code? Why does it not help?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($user_id){
    //creating session
    $user_data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'username' => $username,
        'logged_in' => TRUE,
    );

   $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);            
            // Set message to be sent

   $data['session_data'] = $this->session->all_userdata();

   $this->session->set_flashdata('user_login', 'Welcome');
   $this->load->view('posts', $data);
  //redirect('posts');
} 
  else {
     // Set message to be sent
     $this->session->set_flashdata('login_fail', 'Login Failed');
     redirect('users/login'); 
  }
}
```

at the view,

```
<?php print_r($session_data); ?>
```

if you get your session data into print,
you can display it like,

```
<?= $session_data['user_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Do print_r into your view, 
If your data variable passed properly to your view then you get session_data for sure.

Comment: i can't get anything else on the screen aside the username. i also want to get user email and phone number on the view screen

Comment: You need to set all the data to session that you want,
like that array,

Comment: You are passing just three values into session array,then how you get phone number and email also.

Comment: Please refer this documentation first, 
[https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: What you have done??
at view file you need to print your session just like,
<?php print_r($session_data); ?>
if you get record into your view using this, you have done...

Answer (score -2):

****Modal**

//user login**

```
 function userlogin($data)
    {
        $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "' AND " . "status = '1'";
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("user");
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
         {
        return $query->result();
        } 
        else {  
        return false;
        }       
    }
```

**And in your Controller check**

```
if($this->modal_name->login()==false)
{
//redirect user to login page
}
else
{
  $data['details'] = $this->modal_name->login();
  $this->load->view("post",$data);
}
```

**View**

```
foreach($details as $detail)
{
  echo $detail->id;
  echo $detail->username;
}
```

Comment: Considering the where function is not quoting the username and password - I'm afraid this is a massive case of SQL injection. Where is designed to protect against this if used like where('field',$param).

Comment: You can use $this->db->or_where("field",$value);