# passing user's details in Codeigniter using session

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys I have a User controller and User_model model. I want to be able to retrieve and display a logged in users email and phone number from the database to a view after the user is logged in. any idea how I could go about this would be appreciated and if codes could be written to demonstrate I would be very happy.

MODEL

```
public function login($username, $password){
        //validation
        $this->db->select('id, email, username');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        return $result->row(0)->id;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function login(){
    $data['title'] = 'Login';

    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {

        // fetching user
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
        //Encrypted password
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

    //login user
    $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);

    if($user_id){
        //creating session
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => TRUE,
        );

   $this->session->set_userdata('user_data',$user_data);            
                // Set message to be sent
    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_login', 'Welcome');
    redirect('posts');
    } else {



        // Set message to be sent
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_fail', 'Login Failed');
    redirect('users/login'); 
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have given answer you in most useful way so why you need to ask it again.  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001657/codeigniter-users-data)

Comment: User has asked the same question here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001657/codeigniter-users-data)